# Error on production: /app/app/config/routing.yml

Tags: symfony, production

I have a Symfony 3.3 project.
On my debian local, everything is OK.

But on production... I have this error: 
***The file "/home/blabla/app/app/config/routing.yml" does not exist.***

My host is configured to point on the /web folder.
The .htaccess of the /web folder is the original one provided by Symfony.

Here is my app.php file:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
}

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
}

//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);


// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Really need help, thx !!

Comment: do you have one app dir folder inside one other app dir ?

Comment: you must see in app/config/config.yml file the resource to routing.yml file.

Comment: @M.Galardi 

if I check my config.yml, about routing.yml, I have this: 
`%kernel.project_dir%/config/routing.yml`

About the app folder, I only have one.

Comment: try change "%kernel.project_dir%/config/routing.yml" to " %kernel.project_dir%/../config/routing.yml" in prod mod and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with ..**app/app**/config/routing.yml..

For me this happend when I removed the composer(json,lock) and package(json) files. When you keep them it all works as expected.

Comment: After restore both composer files and clear cache has started working.